# Activities : New Task > Subject "picklist values"

Tags: administration, tasks, activities

Can we have differnt subject picklist values for different object ? When I edited the Task Subject it affects all the the object that has Activities : New Task action

Ex : Account > Activities > New Task > Subject : 1 2 3,
     Leads > Activities > New Task > Subject : 3 2 1,

Comment: Make the Task Subject options dependent on the related object? Pretty sure you would have to write your own UI for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro , u mean visualforce pages/apex ?

Comment: Yes, or Lightning :)